# Angular Material dynamic button toggle group form control accessor

Tags: angular, angular-material

Following the [example in the official demo app](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/button-toggle/button-toggle-demo.html#L50-L57) I wrote this code:

```
<md-button-toggle-group name="typeToggle" [(ngModel)]="chosenType" multiple>
  <md-button-toggle *ngFor="let type of subTypes" [value]="type">
    {{type}}
  </md-button-toggle>
</md-button-toggle-group>
```

But I get the error

```
core.es5.js:1084 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'typeToggle'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'typeToggle'
```

Am I missing something?

---

#### Response to comments:

Removing the `name` attribute results in:

```
core.es5.js:1084 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

Removing `multiple` eliminates the bug but makes it so that the user is only allowed to select one. Select multiple is supported with this syntax according to the Material 2 documentation. Is there another undocumented way to select multiple? I need to be able to select more than one button at a time- I've seen lots of working demos of this behavior.

Comment: `selector: 'md-button-toggle-group:not([multiple])` https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.3/src/lib/button-toggle/button-toggle.ts#L51 Remove `multiple`

Comment: Take off the `name` attribute for `multiple` toggle-groups, especially when using the `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: I responded in an edit above.

Comment: Remove `multiple` attribute – yurzui 25 mins ago

Comment: That gets rid of the error, but takes away the ability to select multiple items. According to the documentation, select multiple is supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why it's broken, but here's a fix.

```
<md-button-toggle-group name="typeToggle" [(ngModel)]="chosenType" multiple ngDefaultControl>
  <md-button-toggle *ngFor="let type of subTypes" [value]="type">
    {{type}}
  </md-button-toggle>
</md-button-toggle-group>
```

to provide some insight, evidently the docs now indicate that `ngModel` is not supported on multiple, and values can be accessed using `(click)`. However, by adding `ngDefaultControl`, the value is accessible. This is as bit of a hack, but so far it works.

Comment: Any advice on getting this to work in reactive forms?